# REACT VITE 3 why "resolve" is not exported by __vite-browser-external?

Tags: reactjs, npm, vite

I have opened an issue
https://github.com/creativetimofficial/soft-ui-dashboard-tailwind/issues/18

When i am going to

```
npm run build
```

I am facing
`'resolve' is not exported by __vite-browser-external, imported by node_modules/vite/dist/node/constants.js file: /Users/user/TerraMotor/project/TMC_GIT/TMC_ADMIN_NEW/node_modules/vite/dist/node/constants.js:1:15 1: import path, { resolve } from 'node:path'; ^ 2: import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url'; error during build: Error: 'resolve' is not exported by __vite-browser-external, imported by node_modules/vite/dist/node/constants.js at error (file:///Users/user/TerraMotor/project/TMC_GIT/TMC_ADMIN_NEW/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:1858:30)`

Problem in node_modules/vite/dist/node/constants.js:1:15

`import path, { resolve } from 'node:path'; import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url';`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnnMg.png)

resolve library to import successfully